# How To Access $(this) in XMLHttpRequest.onload = function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm in an on('blur') listener.  $(this) is my DOM element I'm working on.  I need to continue working on $(this) when my XMLHttpRequest.onload fires.

```
$('#gameListDiv').on('blur','td', function(){
    var myObject = $(this);
    var myRequest = new XMLHttprequest();
    .
    alert(myObject.attr("class")); // popup: "myClass"
    .
    myRequest.onload = function() {
        if (myRequest.status === 200) {
            // How do I pass myObject Here so I can continue working with it?
            alert(myObject.attr("class")); // popup doesn't happen
        }
    }
}
```

How can I pass myObject 'down the line'.  I need to change it's ID based on the responseText of the XMLHttprequest.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question (AmmarCSE's answer is right) - but just wondering, since you're using jQuery anyway, is there a reason you need to use `XMLHttpRequest` instead of `$.ajax()`?

Comment: @MichaelGeary - simply because I am completely new to web/javascript/jquery/ajax and at least one of my books demonstrated using XMLHttpRequest as a way to do what I needed to do (send a database request and use the result) - if $.ajax() is the "new" way, I'll go do some reading about it - thank you.

Comment: Sounds good! There's nothing wrong with using `XMLHttpRequest` - after all, that is how `$.ajax()` is implemented - it's just that `$.ajax()` is simpler to use and takes care of any differences between browsers. In many cases you can use `$.get()` or `$.getJSON()` which are even simpler.

Comment: One more question: Does that book have you generate XML or JSON for the database response from the server? Many older books use XML, but you really should use JSON instead. JSON is *much* simpler to work with in your JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to pass it in. Since you already stored it in a variable within a closure, it is accessible to the `onload`. Just access as it is

```
$('#gameListDiv').on('blur','td', function(){
    var myObject = $(this);
    var myRequest = new XMLHttprequest();
    .
    .
    .
    myRequest.onload = function() {
        if (myRequest.status === 200) {
            myObject//totally legal and same as above
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an alert(myObject.attr('class')) on both sides of myRequest.onload.  Prior to onload, the alert fires.  After onload, the alert does not fire, however a generic alert("Inside") does fire

Comment: @DanA, I dont understand. Is this a problem or observation?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was found.  I was missing a semi-colon within the myRequest.onload statement block that caused erratic results.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble to access your variable, just enchance its scope to make it accesible from any part of the code:

```
var myObject = $("#gameListDiv");

myObject.on('blur','td', function(){
    var myRequest = new XMLHttprequest();
    .
    alert(myObject.attr("class")); // popup: "myClass"
    .
    myRequest.onload = function() {
        if (myRequest.status === 200) {
            // How do I pass myObject Here so I can continue working with it?
            alert(myObject.attr("class")); // popup doesn't happen
        }
    }
}
```

In this `myObject` is `global`.

[See Javascript Scope here.](http://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/)